# Client side asynchronous golang http2

Tags: go, streaming, http2

Is it possible to have client side streaming application in http2 golang?

Something like a client sending a series of numbers and the server responds with a moving average.

All the http.client calls are synchronous and not good for http2.

Comment: You could use [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).

Comment: Please refer https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/#client-streaming-rpc